# Why does the W3 Schools browser check show the wrong browser version for my copy of Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

I've got Internet Explorer 8 installed on my computer, but when I do [this browser check on W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_nav_all) it says that it’s IE6.

- I already checked the compability button,
- I also checked if internet sites, etc runs in compability mode,
- If I press the F12 button, Browser modus = IE8, Documentmodus is also IE8

I don't understand it, is this a bug or what?

Please help me.

Comment: What does "do a browser check" involve?

Comment: when I goto this url from w3schools, you can check your browser version: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=try_nav_all, the thing is. I'm a developer of a webapplication that checks the internet version. If it's lower than IE7, there is no access. Now I'm working with Safari / Chrome / Firefox, but I also have IE8. When I do the browser check, it says that I have IE6 installed

Comment: Given what you've said, I would suggest that you're using an unreliable browser version checker. Find one that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're not confusing the versioning with the browser name?

For example, IE6 is called '6', but the actual version shows up as 4.0:

`Browser Version: 4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; GTB6.6; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)`

Comment: this is the result for IE8 Browser Version: 4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E) 

When I use jQuery "jQuery.browser.version" to check the browser version I also get 6.0,

Comment: Where in that does it say you have IE6 installed? It says `MSIE 8.0` in what you pasted.

Comment: IE6 results: Browser Version: 4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.1)

Answer (score 1):

Curious as to how you are checking- have you tried the IE way?
It returns undefined for anything not IE, or the mode in use on the page if it is IE

```
 navigator.IEmode= (function(){
    /*@cc_on
    @if(@_jscript_version> 5.5){
        return document.documentMode? document.documentMode:
        window.XMLHttpRequest? 7: 6;
    }
    return (@_jscript_version);
    @end
    @*/
})()
alert(navigator.IEmode)
```

Comment: Thx for all the replies and reactions, I tried everything, but still cannot solve the problem. Maybe it has something todo with the developer tools ..? Tears are coming close to me :(